# 12.04 can't find one particular wifi

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I've got the weirdest problem I've ever had.

I have a small HP netboox with Linux 12.04 installed on it. For info: HP mini 5103.

I've used it for weeks: it's always worked perfectly. On multiple wifis, etc.

Since a 2 days I am in Madrid, in a new house, with a new wifi. On my iPhone I get the wifi perfectly and it works without a problem.
Yesterday I turned my computer on and weirdest thing ever:
The home wifi wasn't in the list.
Don'tget me wrong: it detected 35 fcking wifis, but not this one.
I turned it off and on 5 times, both the wifi & the computer, nothing....

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the WiFi indicator and select **Connect to Hidden WiFi Network**

- enter the Network name,
- select the WiFi security
- and enter your password

Then, when you press **Connect** it may, if you are lucky, connect

Comment: Already tried it, sadly it didn't work. Thanks though!

Comment: That's a shame, I had hoped to help... I'll keep looking.

Comment: Try this in terminal `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

Comment: Did it, still the wifi doesn't appear. It's just...not possible.

Comment: Are you using a firewall? if so, disable it... that shouldn't be the answer, but the way things are going, you never know!

Comment: No not using a Firewall normally. I've done a iwlist scanning and it doesn't appear either. I'm going crazy.